# Cambio de color de un texto condicionalmente mediante una funcion

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic, angular8

espero que alguien me ayude con esta implementación, ya que es una ayuda visual para mis usuarios. Tengo una app que estoy desarrollando el cliente mediante ionic 5(angular 8), y al intentar el codigo siguiente, me resulta, pero en consola depurando linea a linea me di cuenta que la funcion que da color al text, está siendo llamada mas de 90 veces y mi array "items", solo tiene 3 item, no me quiero imaginar cuando implemente esto con el servicio que me trae los datos, y ver como colapsa el browser por tantas iteraciones... existe alguna otra forma de hacer este cambio?,
intenté con un ngClass pero también se llama a la función mas de 20 veces con los mismos 3 item.
Saludos y espero que me ayuden.

```
<ion-col *ngFor="let item of items">
 <ion-text [color]="funcion(item.fecha)">{{item.fecha}}</ion-text>
</ion-col>
```

aqui está el codigo de la funcion

```
funcion(elem){
//comparo elem con otro valor 
const ahora = new Date();
const fecha = new Date(ahora.setDate(ahora.getDate()+5));
if(elem > fecha){
   return 'light';
}else{
  return 'danger';
}
}
```

aqui esta el array

```
items = [
{   ...
    fecha: new Date(2020,6,12)
    ...
},
{   ...
    fecha: new Date(2020,5,25)
    ...
},
{   ...
    fecha: new Date(2020,6,30)
    ...
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Para evitar que se calcule cada vez, podrías primero actualizar tu array `items` y agregarle una nueva property a cada objeto.

Luego ya le pasaras a Angular el array de objetos indicando que color utilizar en cada elemento, por lo cual no necesitarás llamar a la función cada vez.

```js
function eligeColor(elem){
  //comparo elem con otro valor 
  const ahora = new Date();
  const fecha = new Date(ahora.setDate(ahora.getDate()+5));
  if(elem > fecha){
     return 'light';
  }else{
    return 'danger';
  }
}

var items = [
{   
    fecha: new Date(2020,6,12)
    
},
{   
    fecha: new Date(2020,5,25)
    
},
{   
    fecha: new Date(2020,6,30)
   
}
];



for (let i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
  items[i].color = eligeColor(items[i].fecha);
}

console.log(items)
```

Comment: pero tendría que modificar el array completo, si es así podría pasar todo la logica del color al backend y asi me trae la propiedad lista y solo tengo que interpolarla, pero quería ver si se puede como logica de front.

Comment: Lo que yo hice lo hice con JS, asi que se puede hacer en el front. No tienes que modificar el array original necesariamente, puedes hacer una copia. La llamada al a funcion la haras de todas maneras para cada elemento, la diferencia es si lo aplicas al principio o dejas que Angular la llame por ti.